# How can selections from a Combo Box be saved / remembered when a new form appears?

Tags: c#, winforms

Say there is a Winform that allows users to answer a question using a Combo Box.  Once they select an answer they can click "Next" and see a new question along with a new Combo Box to select their answers from.

How would the answer from the previous page be saved so that is "Previous" is pressed, that same answer selected previously will still populate *that* Combo Box?

Edit:
The problem I am having with your example is with these two.  "Cannot resolve symbol comboBox1"

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += SelectedAnswerChanged;
question.SelectedChoice = (AnswerChoice)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Hey, it looks like our comments got removed, just wanted to make sure my last comment resolved the issue.

Comment: What was your last comment? I don't think I saw it before it was all removed.

Comment: Check out the DisplayQuestion() method I have below as opposed to what I had before; try using that and see if it fixes it.

Comment: It didn't directly solve my problem but based on your answer I was able to look around and find a good way of solving the problem.  Thanks again so much for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do

**Change your question class to:**

---

```
public class Questions
{
    public string QuestionType { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public Choice[] Choice { get; set; }
    public Choice SelectedChoice { get; set; }
}
```

This adds a `Choice` object to it, allowing us to save a `Choice` that the user selects from the ComboBox

**Change your AnswerChoice class to:**

---

```
public class AnswerChoice
{
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    public Questions Question { get; set; }

    public override void ToString() {
        return AnswerText;
    }
}
```

This just adds an override on the ToString method. What this does is allows us to add the actual object to the ComboBox instead of just the AnswerText. This gives it a bit more object-oriented approach and allows us to save references to this object in the `SelectedChoice` of the Question. If we added the object without the override ToString method then the combobox would display something along the lines of `System.Namespace.ClassHere.AnswerChoice`

**Change your ComboBoxControl class to this:**

---

```
public partial class ComboBoxControl : UserControl
{
    public ComboBoxControl(Questions question)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = question.QuestionText;

        Choice[] choices = question.Choice;

        foreach (var ch in choices)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(ch.AnswerChoice);

            if (ch.IsDefault)
            {
              comboBox1.Text = ch.AnswerChoice;
            }
        }

        // load the saved answer if it exists
        if (question.SelectedChoice != null) {
            comboBox1.Text = string.Empty // not sure if this is needed or not
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = question.SelectedChoice;
        }           
    }
}
```

Two things were changed here:

1. Instead of adding the `ch.AnswerChoice.AnswerText` we add the actual `AnswerChoice` object, allowing us to save references to the actual object for later
2. Anytime a question is loaded it checks to see if the `SelectedChoice` property is null or not. If it isn't, then it sets that object (which has already been loaded) as the `SelectedItem`

**Inside your SurveyView form add this method:**

---

```
private void SelectedAnswerChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Questions question = _presenter.GetQuestion(questionNumber);
    question.SelectedChoice = (Choice)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
}
```

This is the method that we will later tie to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event on the ComboBox we create. This is what will save the choices a user selects.

**Change your DisplayQuestion() method to:**

---

```
private void DisplayQuestion(int questionNumber)
{
    var qNumber = _presenter.GetQuestion(questionNumber);
    if (string.Equals(qNumber.QuestionType, "ComboBoxControl"))
    {
        controlPanel.Controls.Clear();
        var comboBox = new ComboBoxControl(qNumber);
        comboBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += SelectedAnswerChanged;
        controlPanel.Controls.Add(comboBox);
    }
}
```

This just ties the SelectedAnswerChanged method we just put in the SurveryView form to the SelectedIndexChanged event on the ComboBox we create.